# How to redirect browser when posting with PHP file_get_contents?

Tags: php, post, file-get-contents

When I receive a post request to my webserver, I add to the data and post to another webserver using PHP and file_get_contents. The problem is that the browser keeps showing my webserver's url until the user clicks something on the page from the second webserver.

On the other hand, if I take the post my webserver receives, I can send it to the second webserver as a get request and redirect the user's browser at the same time so that they see the second webserver's url in the addressbar before clicking on anything.

How can I make post redirect the browser while posting?

As a side note, because the second website uses relative urls, I have to add a base url to the header tag before sending it to the user so when they click something, it resolves to the correct url.

Here's my post code:

```
  $data = array("key"=>"value",...);
  $options = array(
      "http" => array(
        "header"  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "method"  => "POST",
        "content" => http_build_query($data))
  );
  $stream  = stream_context_create($options);
  $site = file_get_contents($url, false, $stream);
  $site = str_replace('</head>', '<base href="$baseUrl"></head>', $site);
  echo $site;
```

Here's my get code that works fine:

```
  $queryData = http_build_query($data);
  header("location:" . $url . "?" . $queryData);
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Put a `<form>` onto your page, with all the necessary data put into hidden fields, and submit it directly to the URL of the external site ...?

Comment: This is what I did initially--and it works fine, but the second website is not returning all the data to me I need, so I collect what I need first and post the rest to the second site, which then posts only some of the data back to me. Get solves what I need, but I'm trying to avoid the long unsightly query string in the user's browser on their way to the second website.

Comment: _"but the second website is not returning all the data to me I need, so I collect what I need first and post the rest to the second site"_ - unclear what data actually needs to pass from where to where now.

Comment: My real question is whether there is a way to do header(location: url, post_data) to keep long query strings out of the user's browser's address bar. file_get_contents, is close, but it's not redirecting the user's browser when I echo the page back to the user.

Comment: No, you can not "insert" new POST data to send via a Location header.

Comment: Is there some way to use file_get_contents to achieve the same effect? (original question). Hopefully somebody knows a way. For now, I'm using the get method. Thank you.

Comment: You can either have your server act as a proxy in between the browser and the remote target server - which is what you are doing now, and requires that you do stuff like inserting the base element, to ensure that relative URLs do not get resolved against _your_ server's domain; or you can make the browser send a modified request to the remote target server directly. But the latter can not be achieved by any Location header, but only by submitting a form (or making a similar background request via AJAX/fetch, but then the remote party would also have to allow CORS requests.)